# Unable to start docker mongo image on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker

When starting the image I get the following error:

```
 2019-02-27T17:09:41.095+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1551287381:95206][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715:
/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1551287381:95206][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-02-27T17:09:41.108+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.6
2019-02-27T17:09:41.111+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1551287381:111166][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715:
/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1551287381:111166][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-02-27T17:09:41.149+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1551287381:149030][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1551287381:149030][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-02-27T17:09:41.153+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.7
2019-02-27T17:09:41.156+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1551287381:156133][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715:
/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1551287381:156133][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-02-27T17:09:41.177+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1551287381:177375][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1551287381:177375][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-02-27T17:09:41.192+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.8
2019-02-27T17:09:41.194+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1551287381:194762][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715:
/data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1551287381:194762][1:0x7fae36fc4a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2019-02-27T17:09:41.200+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2019-02-27T17:09:41.200+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
2019-02-27T17:09:41.201+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 704
```

The .env folder value is

```
MONGO_SAVE_PATH=./database/db
```

The DB docker file:

```
FROM mongo:latest
VOLUME ["/data/db"]
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

The docker-compose.yml DB container

```
services:
  my-mongo-db:
  build: ./database
  ports:
   - 32815:27017
  volumes:
- ./database/db:/data/db
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. However, on linux and Mac this issue doesn't appear.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> WARNING (Windows & OS X): The default Docker setup on Windows and OS X
>   uses a VirtualBox VM to host the Docker daemon. Unfortunately, the
>   mechanism VirtualBox uses to share folders between the host system and
>   the Docker container is not compatible with the memory mapped files
>   used by MongoDB (see vbox bug, docs.mongodb.org and related
>   jira.mongodb.org bug). This means that it is not possible to run a
>   MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host.

[Answer from docker mongo GitHub](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/232#issuecomment-355423692)

Workaround to persist data:

```
docker volume create --name=mongodata
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v mongodata:/data/db --name=mymongo mongodb:3.3
```

More info [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74)

Comment: thank you for your reply but I'm not using virtual box I'm using VM.

Comment: This answer still holds true even with the default distro of desktop docker on windows using Hpyer-V. Use the docker volume create and you will be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to change the commands above in order to work with docker-compose, I am getting the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147270/docker-compose-and-mongodb-failed-to-start-up-wiredtiger-under-any-compatibilit

Answer (score 18):

If you are using docker-compose then following is the way replicate the answer above.

```
services:
  mongodb_container:
    ...
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Please note that the sample above indicates only needed parts of the yml file for the mongodb storage.

Comment: hi where does the mongodata volume end up being mapped to in windows?

Comment: @paul Unlike bind mounts volumes doesn't map to any windows folder location directly. It is completely managed by docker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess you just copy out any files manually if you want to persist them?

Comment: @paul Actually docker volumes are persistent. They don't get deleted unless you explicitly delete them. Getting data out of it is another story. May be you could you a data backup tool for Mongo

Comment: And gues what? Data is not persisted between `docker-compose up` runnings

Comment: @standalone That's bit strange. They don't go off with the containers. They should be removed explicitly.

Comment: @charitha actually, you was right and it works. I was missing `--build` flag. So to apply changes and fully restart exist containers we need to do `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: don't forget to put `version: '3'` above `services`

Comment: There should be another blank line after `mongodata:` else there seems to a error thrown by compose version 2.3

Answer (score 6):

Although [Augustas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278129/augustas) is right, but I found [this](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2014#issuecomment-468895063) answer particularly useful with `docker-compose.yml`.

What you can do as a workaround  is:

1. Create a `.env` file in the same path as your `docker-compose` file and store the current path in an environment variable like this:

```
MONGO_HOST_DATA=/Users/user123/MyMongoProject //path to mongo data folder (for C:\Users\user123\MyMongoProject)
```

2. Now, in your `docker-compose` file, replace the above-mentioned variable:

```
    services:
      my-mongo-db:
      build: ./database
      ports:
       - 32815:27017
      volumes:
    - ${MONGO_HOST_DATA}/database/db:/data/db
```

- If you want to see how the actual path replaced the environment variable, you can use the following command:

```
docker-compose config
```

Additionally, if you use any disk drive other than C:\ you might want to change the Docker file sharing settings:

[image: Windows Docker settings window]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I tried this but i couldnt get it to work. I created a file called .env in the folder next to the docker-compose.yml but it still doesnt work. Is there any way to test the .env file is being read? Im using asp.net core in visual studio

Comment: Yes, actually, as I also mentioned about, you can run `docker-compose config`. It should show you the the actual file content after all the placeholders replaced by the actual values

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got this working in the end, but mongo still throws the same errors. I can see it writing all the WiredTiger.wt.2 files (with the number going up). is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: It depends on what kind of error you're getting. Can you check the logs using `docker logs <container-id-or-name>`?

Comment: thanks for the help. i created a new question so i could include the logs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345030/unable-to-run-a-mongodb-container-in-docker-for-windows-using-linux-file-system . The log file repeats the lines i pasted

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was caused by NTFS permissions while running Mongo on WSL2. Moving to ext4 (WSL partition) fixed it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31240018)

Comment: That was my exact problem. I was running my container under WSL, but using a folder located in my local NTFS drive. As soon as I started my docker environment in a ext4 WSL partition, everything worked as a charm.

Comment: This does indeed provide an answer to the question. Nice work! I don't know what triggered it, because it had been working find on my NTFS partition (`/mnt/c/...`) until it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely the same issue, but I saw the same error messages when simply spinning up a Docker container for mongo in Ubuntu and attempting to mount an existing directory to the container:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -p 27017:27017 -v $PWD/db-data:/data/db -d mongo
```

In my case the errors only showed up if I was trying to run the command from a directory on my mounted HDD, and I was able to solve it by migrating my codebase with the /db-data directory to my SSD where Ubuntu is installed.