# Spring Boot app and MongoDB on different Docker containers. App not starting

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I encounter this weird problem and i tried a lot of different suggestions found here, but nothing worked in the end.

To summarize: I have a Spring Boot app which uses a mongodb database. I want to start the application and the database using docker-compose but the app is not starting.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine


VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080

ADD target/batch-jobs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar batch-jobs.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://docker_mongo:27017/batchjobs","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","batch-jobs.jar"]
```

***docker-compose*** file

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - gateway
    container_name: docker_mongo
    hostname: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: batch-jobs
    networks:
      - gateway
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

networks:
  gateway:
    driver: bridge
```

***application.properties****

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=docker_mongo
spring.data.mongodb.database=batchjobs
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://docker_mongo:27017/batchjobs
```

Ok, the weird thing now is that if i change in .properties the host from `docker-mongo` into `localhost` i can start the app from local with mongo database started from compose.

If i leave the host like this with the same name as the container_name, i cannot start it even from local.

The error i'm getting when i try to start my app from docker-compose:

```
2021-03-23 19:52:45.337  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'csvJobController' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/app/batch-jobs.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/daninovac/batch/jobs/web/CsvJobController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'csvJobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/app/batch-jobs.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/daninovac/batch/jobs/service/CsvJobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csvDataRepository' defined in com.daninovac.batch.jobs.repository.CsvDataRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
2021-03-23 19:52:45.343  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-23 19:52:45.368  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-23 19:52:45.378 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'csvJobController' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/app/batch-jobs.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/daninovac/batch/jobs/web/CsvJobController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'csvJobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/app/batch-jobs.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/daninovac/batch/jobs/service/CsvJobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csvDataRepository' defined in com.daninovac.batch.jobs.repository.CsvDataRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.daninovac.batch.jobs.BatchJobsApplication.main(BatchJobsApplication.java:16) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[batch-jobs.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[batch-jobs.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[batch-jobs.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[batch-jobs.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'csvJobService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/app/batch-jobs.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/daninovac/batch/jobs/service/CsvJobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csvDataRepository' defined in com.daninovac.batch.jobs.repository.CsvDataRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csvDataRepository' defined in com.daninovac.batch.jobs.repository.CsvDataRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at 
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.validateConfiguration(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:79) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.computeClientSettings(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

**Later edit:**
Seems like it's a different behavior somehow. On my mac machine i had the error before. And on Windows i have this:

```
2021-03-24 12:22:17.321  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

The container and the app are running, but the connection to mongodb is not working.

I would like to run both mongo & my app from `docker-compose up` but i tried a lot of different combinations with the configs (even with the uri in .properties, that's why i left the comment there) but i cannot succeed.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Made it work. I did a couple changes, i think the problem was the fact that i didn't specified the env variables which should run on my application from docker-compose file.

These are the configs that worked for me. I can run it with docker-compose, an i can also run it from local.

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo
    hostname: mongo
    networks:
      - main-network
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
      - mongodata:/var/log/mongodb
      - mongodata:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: [ "--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0" ]

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: batch-jobs
    image: batch-jobs
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=databasename
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - main-network

networks:
  main-network:
    external:
      name: batchjobs-network

# needed in order to work properly on Windows:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911021/unable-to-start-docker-mongo-image-on-windows
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine

EXPOSE 8080

# run app
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} batch-jobs.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/batch-jobs.jar"]
```

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=databasename
```